# Android - number of opened file descriptors per application

Tags: android, count, file-descriptor

I went through several posts about how much opened files can I have in applications. All says about 256 up to 1024. They are using below code for testing

```
    struct rlimit limit;
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &limit);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FDTEST", "fd limit cur=%d max=%d", limit.rlim_cur, limit.rlim_max);
```

I tested two devices today, first is Google Pixel 3XL, second is Samsung s20FE. I always get values above 32k

```
fd limit cur=32768 max=32768
```

How is it possible, is these detection routine wrong? Or was that limit increased in newer Android versions?

Comment: Why dont you just code it yourself? Make a loop and see how many files you can open.

Comment: Should I run this test on every device to get the limit? Isn't better to get this info from system?

Comment: If you do not believe those 32K's then just try i said. I dont believe them either.

Comment: It throws "Too many open files" by around 500

Comment: Ok. At 512? And now? What do you want?

Comment: It's in my question, "is these detection routine wrong? Or was that limit increased"...If it is wrong, how to detect the limit

Comment: Well it seems to be wrong isnt it? And it is in between 256 and 1024. So what is the question?  I think determining yourself is the way to go.

Comment: isn't that clear? how to detect the limit

Comment: 256 looks a lot to me. A few years ago on Windows it was 49.

Comment: By normal system yes, by slow android scoped storage it is low, 2000 would be all right, maybe. But I need detect the limit on device

Comment: That was on first device, on second device I successfully opened 2000. So, be now smart